# Lebesgue Integral of function multiplied by infinity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

In Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis there is a following proposition:

> **1.24**
>
> *Let $f$ be measurable function, $E$ measurable set, and $\mu$ a measure. Then if $f \geqslant 0$ and $c$ is a constant, $0 \leqslant c < \infty,$ then*
>   $\int_Ecfd\mu = c\int_Efd\mu.$

This one is pretty obvious, but I'm confused with assumption that $c < \infty.$ I am pretty sure that equality still holds for $c = \infty.$ Or am I wrong?

Comment: Exercise 13 for Chapter One.

Comment: @DanielFischer so it is true for $c=\infty,$ thanks! But how can I mark the question as answered if the answer is in comment?

Comment: I'll post an answer, just a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the equality also holds for $c = \infty$. Rudin was aware of that, exercise 13 of the first chapter is to prove that.

The case $c = \infty$ is however not relevant to the further development of the theory, hence there is no compelling reason to include it in the statement of 1.24.